# Basic Range Based For loop not running?

Tags: c++

Hi I am just testing a range based for loop just to familiarize myself with it. This program should just allow a user to input 4 names and then it will output 4 names.I believe I am doing it correctly but I am getting compilers errors when I try to compile. If I remove the range based part and I use the part I have //'d out it works fine.

Is there something wrong with my code?

names.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

names.cpp:18: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token

names.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’

names.cpp:21: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’

names.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’

names.cpp:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘return’

```
 #include"iostream"
  #include"string"

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {

  string names[4];
  cout<<"input names\n";

  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
  cin>>names[i];}

// The following 2 lines work
  //for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
  //cout<<names[i]<<endl;}

// the following 2 lines do not work
  for(string val : names){
  cout << val << endl;}

  return 0;}
```

Comment: Compiles/runs fine for me: http://ideone.com/I2DbRN

Comment: I tried switiching names and val around : and I am still unable to compile.

Comment: Could be a pre-C++11 compiler... what compiler and what version are you using, and what arguments (if any) are you passing to it?

Comment: Could it be that my compiler just doesnt know what : means?

Comment: Using a compiler on linux terminal. command I use is g++ (filename) -o (executable name)

Comment: try asking gcc to use c++11 standard. I think it is "-std=c++0x".

Comment: I was reading through a c++ book and the example in the book shows what I have but it is using an int and not a string which is why I think I did it right. I dont think the compiler knows less than me but I agree with Sneftel that it might be outdated?

Comment: Yes, see my answer where I explain that and give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you didn't tell us what compiler & version you're using, the syntax error is a dead giveaway!

**You're using a C++11 feature, the ranged-based for loop.**

But your compiler is in C++03 mode (or is actually a pre-C++11 compiler).

For recent GCC, add `-std=c++11` (well, `-std=c++14`) to your `g++` invocation on the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a gcc version prior to 6.1 you have to add "-std=c++11" to your compiler flags.

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious that the point of the rep-to-comment barrier is to encourage you to _watch and learn_ before commenting so that you can be assured to have learnt how the site works first. It's not there to encourage you to post your comment in the wrong place instead, so _please don't do that_. Comments posted as answers will simply be removed. However, as it happens, this is a good _answer_ to the posed question. I'm removing your intro about lack of commenting ability.

Comment: I agree with what @Light wrote